# DJANGO: Displaying a PNG picture into an HTML template

Tags: python, html, django

I have been struggling with an issue and similar questions on this website haven't helped me. I am learning Django and I want to print an image PNG (which I generate with Python) into an HTML page (so, following Django's rules, I use an HTML template). To create my picture I have written some code into a SEPARATED views.py file (which I have called views1.py), here is the content:

```
from pylab import figure, axes, pie, title
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot
from django.http import HttpResponse 


def test_matplotlib(request):
    f = figure(figsize=(6,6))
    ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
    fracs = [15,30,45, 10]
    explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)
    pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
    title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(f)    
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    matplotlib.pyplot.close(f)
    return response
```

In my views.py I have defined a function, which lets a user search for the ticker of a stock. When he submits the request, the user will see the price of the stock in that moment, here is my function (this function works, I have tested it):

```
 # import some packages (for the answer, ignore those that are not related, I have other functions in this views.py file)
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from yahoo_finance import Share
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def enterTicker(request):
    errors = []
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        ticker = q
        ticker2=Share('%s'%ticker)
        pricetoday=ticker2.get_price()
        if not q:
            errors.append('Enter a valid ticker.')
        elif(pricetoday==None):
            errors.append('Enter a valid ticker.')
        else:
            return render(request, 'search_results.html',
                      {'query': q, 'ticker': q, 'pricenow': pricetoday})
    return render(request, 'search_form.html',
              {'errors': errors})
```

In my urls.py file I did this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite import views, views1

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^search/$', views.enterTicker),    
    ...,
]
```

And, finally, I have my template search_results.html:

```
<html>     
    <head>         
    <title>Book Search</title>     
    </head>     
    <body>       
        <p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

        {% if ticker %}           
            <p>The price of {{ ticker }} in this moment is {{ pricenow }}.</p>

        <img src="../views1.py" />

        {% else %}           
            <p>No tickers matched your search criteria.</p>       
        {% endif %}     
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody understand why the link between the PNG picture which I generate in my views1.py and my HTML template is not working? Thank you very much, I'm really stuck on this

Comment: Is that really the `src` value of your img? It makes no sense; it should link to a URL, not a Python file.

Comment: that is exactly what I thought, then I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335124/using-matplotlib-with-django-generic-views someone is saying this is how you do it, I find it just odd

Comment: You've misunderstood what that link is telling you. It says that the src should be the "path to that view url"; in other words, the URL that serves the `test_matplotlib` view. You should add an entry to your urls.py that uses `views1.test_matplotlib`, and use that URL in the src.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel, I was sure that the mistake was small and embarassing